# How to tar files to pointed folder of archive?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to write my own script for comfortable tar-usage (and also become more experienced in shell), and I am stuck. I want to if user cast `my_script pack name.tar file1 file2` - create main folder in archive in pack files to it - how to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by main folder?  This question is very unclear.

Comment: @Benj a parent folder in the archive, that contains all the files

Comment: Reading the manual for whatever you want to ask about might help avoid downvotes due to no research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modifying File and Member Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/transform.html#SEC113) in the GNU tar Manual.